# How do i call view with fresh URL after passing data to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used below url to call my product view:

```
example.com/diamondshop/index.php/product/view
```

The Sample of view function in product controller:

```
function view($msg = "") {
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    $this->load->view('product', $data);
}
```

By clicking 'Add to Cart' button, I call the controller as below url:

```
example.com/diamondshop/index.php/product/addcart/3
```

Here, 3 is my product Id.

The Sample of addcart function in product controller:

```
function addcart($pid) {
    //
    // My code to add in cart
    //
    $this->view("Item Added to Cart.");
}
```

I am now on product view again, but after loading view my URL remain as it is:

```
example.com/diamondshop/index.php/product/addcart/3
```

but, I want fresh URL like above when i first time call product view:

```
example.com/diamondshop/index.php/product/view
```

So, how do i call product view with fresh URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is CodeIgniter is just jumping from one function to another within the same request (i.e. from the `addcart` to `view`) which doesn't change your URL. You need to do a header redirect at the end of the `addcart` function if you want the URL to change. This can be done with the [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) and it's `redirect` method.

```
redirect('/product/view');
```

Concerning the second parameter, here is what the manual says:

> The optional second parameter allows you to choose between the "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method. Location is faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the redirect function:

```
redirect('/product/view/', 'refresh');
```

Add this after `$this->view("Item Added to Cart.");`

Here's some more URL helpers: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html